# How to use jquery.cookie.js file only with html?

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on one project where I am doing html and jquery work and there was cgi at server side. Now we want to implement login/logout feature into it, but problem is we did not use any scripting language like php. 
I want to use jquery.cookie.js to generate cookie and send it along with each request to server. My problem is how can I generate only one cookie for all pages for particular browser, so same cookie can send to server.If user knows the page name then he can access it directly like (http://www.mydomain.com/page.html). I have only use html so I have to include all js and css on each page.

If any other alternative for the same purpose then acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery.cookies.js simply helps you to set/modify/remove/get cookies in browser (default built in interface is not very handy for this)

Once you set it - each next request will contain that cookie automatically. Cookies have multiple settings like available for some path only (for instance, you may tell browser to send cookies only if it page has path like www.example.com/path_with_cookie/* ) or when it should expire. Just open docs for of your plugin and read how you can set different options with your script. Once cookie is set - it will be sent with any request which meats requirements like domain and path until it is not removed or expired.

But I do not see how you can create login/logout thing without any server side codding. Well, you may hide/show some elements in browser with js/css but without server being involved into that (usually server will check if user is logged in using cookie and make decision based on that if some content should be shown to user or not) it will be useless. Once some content delivered to browser anyone who knows how JS/HTML works can see hidden content. Plus - you need to check somehow if login/password is correct - have no idea how that could be done without server side coding and still being secure.

**UPD:**

If you still have to put cookies into form, you can add code like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').live("submit", function(){
       $(this).append($("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"auth_cookie\">").val($.cookie('auth_cookie')));
    });
});
```

Another way (for newer version of jquery, `live` is now deprecated):

```
$(document).on("submit", 'form', function(){...});
```

This code will catch submit event and add hidden field to any form which is submitted. Of course, it should be added on any page where form is available.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. we have used cgi on server side as I have mentioned into my question,and we have authenticate user name and password using cgi and then based on cookie we have tried to manage user session. I have read document of plugin. I know how to create cookie, but my problem is,from where I can call that function to generate cookie, after it on each page how can I manage to not set cookie if once generated. Hope you understand if not come again.

Comment: Actually, if you authenticate users with cgi, you should set cookies on server side, after authentication is successfull. You simply do not need jquery.cookies.js in that case.

Comment: Yes you are right, we already tried this, but the problem is we have used c language for cgi and to maintain cookie for different users is more burden for us, as we have common username and password (ie. only one user).How can we differentiate each login request? so, we decided to send cookie from client side.

Comment: I have tried to create cookie and successfully created it, also solve problem which I have mentioned in my first comment.Now problem is how to set this cookie into hidden field of each form on each page with same name,so server side cgi will get it and do further process based on it.Thanks for your suggestion into your answer, based on it I have created cookie.

Comment: Oh! If your cookie is created correctly (open developer tools, should be opened by pressing F12, in chrome and check resources tab. There is a line Cookies - it will show all cookies available for that page) it will be sent by browser. Automatically. You do not need to place them in form fields. Cookie will be sent in request header. And on server you should be able to get them from request. How that should be done depends on your server side language.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have already check cookie into chrome, and it is created as expected. Into my server side code, we did not get headers we have to get only post variables. So, we need to set it into form hidden field.If you have any alternative please tell me.

Comment: `we did not get headers we have to get only post variables` are you sure? Well, I can imagine situation like that, but I do not believe it is not possible to change. What tools/language do you have running on your server to serve requests?

Comment: Also, see update. There is a code which you can use to add cookies into a form on client side. But still - that is bad approach. Double check if you **really** can't access cookies received with headers on server side.

Comment: Thanks for reply and update. I have just set cookie into hidden field of each page through jquery. You code is also good.I have talked with the guy who worked on cgi, he told me that may be we can get headers, for that he has to on one service on server.So, we will check and come back here.

Comment: OK,done,we got headers though our server side code. Thanks a lot for your kind help.+1 for it.

Comment: I have one other question, can you help me for that? or I will asked it separately.

Comment: Suppose another question would be better. If I do not know an answer - somebody else may help you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21815/discussion-between-pkachhia-and-fangel)

Comment: can we continue this discussion in chat?